# A php script that I want it be run by Transmission client!

Tags: scripts, php, transmission, torrent-client

In transmission-gtk there is an option can run script: **Edit > Preferences > Downloading > Call script when torrent is completed**.

Recently, I found [this script](http://oguzarduc.blogspot.com/2012/05/transmission-quit-script-in-php.html) that I do not know how to make it work under transmission. According to the program description, the script does not turn off the system, but it can kill transmission after all torrents are done. that's enough for me because I can chain "*turning off*" to "*closing transmission*" by `&&`.

Now, may you, guys, help me to run this php script under transmission?

this is an example mentioned by the script author:
`php.exe Transmission_Quit.php --port=9999 --hostname=192.168.0.1`; what does this mean?! how should I use it? Should I point it to "*Call script when torrent is completed*" option directly?

Comment: The mention of "php.exe" in the "example mentioned by the script author" seems to have something to do with a Windows based system. Are you trying this in a Windows system? in Ubuntu php.exe may fail. Please inform. Thank you.

Comment: :o Is [transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) available on windows?

Comment: This link says so: Transmission-Qt Win is a build of transmission-qt for Windows. ==> http://sourceforge.net/projects/trqtw/

Comment: Good news, I'll share it to my friends. However, the reference hints: *PHP **CLI** script* --> cli

Comment: there is also "cli" in Windows. Formerly known as command.com and more recently known as cmd.com console. :) Additionally, the php code that you refer can be used both in Windows or Linux. :)

Answer (score 3):

***I am leaving this in order to follow up the original question which is asking to run a specific php script. But a workaround is provided in the New Recipe section in order to solve the main problem.***

Please try this and inform on your results, after which this answer may be changed or deleted:

*At a certain moment your password may be asked.*

1. First of all, let's create a file called script.php by dropping in a
   terminal `sudo gedit script.php` (remember that you can drop this
   file in whatever folder you wish but for testing purposes your home
   folder will be good).
2. In the file, let's copy/paste the contents of the script that you
   mention. Save the file and close it down.
3. Now let's give the file the proper file permissions and the
   execution permission also by dropping the next two lines in a
   terminal, one line at once.

   sudo chmod 755 script.php

   sudo chmod a+x script.php
4. Now, let's install php5-cli by dropping in a terminal `sudo apt-get
   install php5-cli` and let's wait the terminal to finish the install
   process.

Once `php5-cli` is installed we can test the script by invoking `php script.php  --port=9999 --hostname=192.168.0.1;` in a terminal, but it will be better if you do it from inside of Transmission.

[**php5-cli**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5620586/) is a command line interpreter for the PHP5 Scripting Language and it is useful to run php scripts like this, it is more like the php.exe file for Windows, the one that you refer on your original question.

I hope you succeed but please inform on your results in order to provide the proper support or delete this answer if not useful.

### Addendum

After reading your comments, I give you this fast-food recipe for the php script.

First of all I need to explan certain things of the example given by the script's author, as follows:

```
script.php  --port=9999 --hostname=192.168.0.1;
```

- `--port=9999` = 9999 is an example port, but in this field you should
  write the same port number that you define on the Web client tab.
- `--hostname=192.168.0.1` = Must be the ip of the equipment that you wish the script run to kill transmission's process.

This makes me think that the process can be invoked remotely but for our particular case we are going to use the default values so that we need not to include neither the port nor the hostname. By simply running the `script.php` file in a terminal or invoked by transmission and it's going to use the default values which apply to our computer (`localhost`).

### Then, let's cook fast food:

1. We need a file, let's call it bye.sh and place it somewhere, your
   home folder is a good place for testing purposes.
2. Insert the next inside of the file ([fast food script here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5623014/)),
   save it, close it and give it execution permissions. (for reference,
   go down on this answer and find how).

[image]

- Then, serve it inside of your Transmission "Download" tab but make
  sure you include the proper bye.sh file to be invoked when the
  download finishes.

[image]

That's it. *I need to explain that somehow, the php script is succeeding but it observes a small delay after the downloads finishes and I have just tested with 2 small torrent files. I can't say if the delay will increase if the list is longer or the download size is heavier, behavior that is not observed by the New Recipe formula. However, the PHP file gives you the warranty that it's going to run in whatever OS that is PHP capable, and my New Recipe is mostly intended for Linux Based Systems, it works on Ubuntu and may succeed in other distributions, Debian or Ubuntu based, and certain modifications will allow it to succeed in other non Debian/Ubuntu based distributions.*

Good luck!

## New Recipe

OK I have a new recipe for this case, I admit it got all my attention, even when I don't use Transmission so often.

## The Recipe

### Ingredients

1. transmission-gtk (installed somehow, from the software bag,
   terminal, etc.)
2. transmission-cli (sudo apt-get install transmission-cli, provide
   password, wait the install to finish.)
3. [The Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5620586/). (cooked apart)

### Preparation

- Let's prepare our transmission in order to receive web client
  petitions from outside, this way we can monitor what is happening in
  our program. Let's open Transmission and go to the "Web" tab in order
  to enable the "Enable web client" checkbox as shown in the next
  screenshot.

[image]

*(Default values will do the trick perfectly)*

- Let's open our favorite text editor in order to create a file named
  `byebye.sh` and let's place the next contents inside. (See the script [**here**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5620586/))

[image]

Now, let's find the bybye.sh file and give it the proper execution permissions by dropping in a terminal `sudo chmod a+x bybye.sh` or by entering the file properties in Nautilus and activating the "Allow executing file as program" checkbox in the "Permissions" as shown in the next screenshot.

[image]

- Once we cooked out the script, let's install `transmission-cli`, in a
  terminal drop: `sudo apt-get install transmission-cli`, hit Enter and
  provide your password, after which the software will be installed.

### Time for tasting

In a terminal, drop `transmission-remote --list | sed '1d;$d' | grep -v Done | wc -l` after which the results may vary from case to case, depending on the amount of torrents that are pending or currently downloading in transmission. If the results is different than `0` we're on our way. If you receive `0` and something is downloading or in queue, you must check the recipe from the beginning. If you receive an error please drop it in a comment in order to provide support.

- If everything is going fine, now let's instruct transmission to run
  the script everytime a torrent is completed. **CALM DOWN!** Please,
  calm... the script will run each time a torrent is completely
  download, but it will only trigger the action to terminate
  transmission just when the results of downloads equals zero. This
  conditional way give us the tranquility that transmission won't close
  down on each download. A screenshot is provided for your convenience:

[image]

And voila! The recipe can be served in generous portions and in company of all your downloads. Transmission will close down just if the last download succeeded.

### SOME WARNINGS

If Transmission is having only one pending action and the download finishes at the very moment of the software's opening, Transmission is going to close as soon as it opens.

### Glossary:

`killall -9 transmission` = Will close transmission in a gently mode so that you won't receive an error message each time it is closed. By simply using `killall transmission` is going to close it in an rude way thus the software will report a close failure.

Now, make sure you include a glass with excellent Cuban rum for me in the table when serving the recipe and...

Good luck!

Comment: Ok I have added a new recipe with a workaround on how to solve your main problem, which I expect works without issues for you as it does for me. Both the PHP and the New Recipe solutions are working this side but somehow the New Recipe is doing a better work. I suggest you to try this new workaround and I am sure it is going to work. Please let me know if something is wrong and if you receive an error don't hesitate to drop it down right here to continue the support. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have included an Addendum to the original php recipe in order to show how to include the php script in a sh file and allow transmission to execute it. I have also made the edition to the installation of php5-cli as you suggested and I am going to include my ticket in the pages that you suggested as soon as it is possible to me. I am going to consider improving the code after reading the post you suggest me but the codes that I have placed on the answer are working pretty fine, but if it can be improved be sure that I will do it. Thank you for the suggestions and observations. :)

Comment: Doesn't it need to add `Address:HTTPport` between `transmission-remote` and `--list` according to [web tab details](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZhYc.png)? -however, I don't know anything about network :( Also I deleted my comments to make the answer more clear and clean. this comment will be removed soon, too.

Comment: Just if you change the default values. If you are using default values you can run it without any parameters, transmission-remote will assume you are using the proper default parameters and will return the proper results. I suggest you not to delete the comments because of my comments looks like a foolish monologue if your comments aren't there. :D Additionally, our comments will be useful for further visitors. Thank you!

Comment: `killall -9 transmission` will not close transmission in "a gently mode", it'll kill it outright, leaving it no chance to clean up and save its state and configuration. To close it in a nice way, run `transmission-remote --exit`. Do *NOT* send it SIGKILL (-9). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/690631/347411